# What's the probability a 3x3 circulant matrix with natural coefficients < n is nonsignular?

Tags: matrices, determinant, products, circulant-matrices

What's the probability a $3 \times 3$ circulant matrix with natural coefficients $< n$ is nonsignular?

A circulant matrix $C$ has the form:

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}
c_0 & c_1 & c_2 \\
c_2 & c_0 & c_1 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

From [Wikipedia's Circulant matrix entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Determinant) we have that the determinant equals

$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{c_0 + c_1 \omega^{1 k}+ c_2 \omega^{2 k}}$$

where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / 3}$.

You can assume that each natural number is equally likely to be picked.

Comment: Empirical evidence gives that there are exactly $n$ singular matrices of that form. So the probability is $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @lhf Unless $0$ is excluded, in which case you have $(n-1)^3$ matrices available and $n-1$ of them are singular, giving $1-1/(n-1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're looking for natural number triples that solve at least one of the equations

$$a+b+c=0 \\
a+be^{2\pi i/3}+ce^{4\pi i/3}=0 \\
a+be^{4\pi i/3} + e^{8\pi i/3}=0$$
where the latter can be rewritten as

$$a+be^{4\pi i/3}+ce^{2\pi i/3}=0.$$

Since you have natural numbers the first one is either unsolvable or has the unique solution $a=b=c=0$ depending on your convention for the natural numbers.

Looking at the second and third ones, they are essentially the same; you simply have that a solution to the second equation can have $b$ and $c$ permuted and yield a solution to third equation instead. That said, if you examine the real and imaginary parts of, say, the second equation, you should arrive at the solution rather quickly.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I believe.  I just realized that since we're dealing with naturals less than $n$, the equation for the determinant has a $1/p$ chance of equaling $0 \bmod p$, for $p$ prime.  I believe this is all that we need.

Comment: @MattGroff Where did modular arithmetic come into it? The question was about it being singular over $\mathbb{R}$, wasn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's singular over $r$, sorry.